# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contract.Account

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

i'm trying to build query Dynamically for Contract object.

```
    public Contract con {get;set;}
    ConId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('ConId');
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> fMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    fieldMap = fMap.get('Contract').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
         if (fieldMap.size() > 0){
             for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){

                if(Str == null)
                    Str = sfield.getDescribe().getname();
                    else
                Str += ','+sfield.getDescribe().getname();

        }
    }
    string query = 'Select  '+ Str +' from Contract  where id =: ConId';
    con =  database.query(query);
```

Comment: Where are you using "Contract.account" field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.getGlobalDescribe() dose not return Contract.account field so it is not available in query string but some where you are trying to get the field "Contract.Account" which is throwing error.

to overcome this error you can add this field and query object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no field named `Account` on contract object. However AccountId exists.

It seems like you are referencing parent record in that case you should add following field in query:

```
String query = 'Select  Account.Whatever_The_Custom_Field__c, '+ Str +' from Contract  where id =: ConId';
```

Parent or Child record cannot come in global describe object variable. It only result current described object fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the kind of relationship query you required using inner describes.

Each `Schema.SObjectField` is having a method called `getReferenceTo()` which return `List<Schema.SObjectType>` if the `Schema.SObjectField` is a reference field. So using this we can determine whether the field is a relationship field or not and if it is, we can do inner describe to get the fields of the relationship object.

I just added single level of inner describe to the code snippet of yours.

```
public Contract con {get;set;}
ConId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('ConId');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> fMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
fieldMap = fMap.get('Contract').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
if (fieldMap.size() > 0){
    for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){                
        if(Str == null)
            Str = sfield.getDescribe().getname();
        else
            Str += ','+sfield.getDescribe().getname();
        if(sfield.getDescribe().getReferenceTo() != NULL && sfield.getDescribe().getReferenceTo().size() == 1) {
            fieldMap1 = sfield.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0].getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            if (fieldMap1.size() > 0){
                 for(Schema.SObjectField sfield1 : fieldMap1.Values()){                
                    if(Str == null)
                        Str = sfield.getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.' + sfield.getDescribe().getname();
                    else
                        Str += ','+Str = sfield.getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.' + sfield.getDescribe().getname();;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
string query = 'Select  '+ Str +' from Contract  where id =: ConId';
con =  database.query(query);
```

This will query all of the fields of the relationship fields in `Contract` object. You could just check for the `Account` object and execute the inner describe only for that object.

Hope it helps.